# Git is it possible to show the current tag of a submodule?

Tags: git, tags, git-submodules

is it possible to show the tag of a current submodule without having to be inside its directory?

I would want to do something like

```
git describe --tags <submodule_dir>
```

and return the particular tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git submodule foreach` ([doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt)) to run a command from within each submodule :

```
# something like the following should work :
git submodule foreach 'echo $name : `git describe --tags`'
```

---

For a command such as `git describe` (which extracts its information only from the `.git/` directory, not from the working tree), you can pass the git directory as an argument to the `git` command :

```
# the .git directory for a submodule can be found under .git/modules/module_name :
git --git-dir=.git/modules/module_name describe --tags
```